# How to debug with intellij?

Tags: intellij-13

I have a web application, and I put debug breakpoints in the servercode.
I downloaded the chrome JetBrains extension.
And setup the run/debug configurations according to the instructions in intellij's help pages.

Why does it not stop on debug points when i run the server in debug mode ?

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but are you running your server code in the IntelliJ IDE? Is it multithreaded?

Comment: yes i am running my server code in ide, and internal ide tomcat. I'm not sure if it's multithreaded,it is a Java Servlet and doPost method

Comment: Have you tried this? http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200408/DebuggingServer-sideCode.html
Posting screenshots of what you've done might help

Comment: yes, unfortunately still no go

Comment: Will your code breakpoint _anywhere_ or just not where you think it should?

Comment: i put a breakpoint in "doPost" and its not stopping at all.
the client side is built on a bunch of post requests to the servlet, any button click, any refresh, any anything should result in a call to the doPost method in the servlet, and it doesnt ?

Comment: I suppose I was asking if there's any code you know will _have_ to execute, even independent of the client, then you would be able to tell if your setup was indeed not properly configured. Perhaps we need to see some screenshots

Comment: @RyanJ I put a breakpoint in initiating the server's database, and it does stop there. I want it to stop in doPost - and seems that doPost of the servlet is multithreaded, how do i make it stop in it?

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ doesn't like threads when it comes to breakpoints for some reason, as the [suspend policy](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/breakpoints.html#suspend) probably needs to be configured. By default, the policy is to suspend all threads, but the behavior probably noticed is that it won't stop, and you will only be able to "snapshot" your given state.

Try setting the suspend policy on your breakpoints to "Thread" and see if that works for you.

Right click on a breakpoint to get this dialog:

[image]

Comment: for unknown reasons it still doesnt stop there :(